# Does animating an element deep in the DOM really hurt performance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, animation

I read [the following](http://javascript.info/tutorial/animation) and it got me thinking

> Help the browser to render
>
> The browser manages rendering tree, and
>   elements depend on each other. If the animated element is deep in the
>   DOM, then other elements depend on it’s geometry and position. Even if
>   the animation actually doesn’t shift them, the browser has to perform
>   additional calculations.
>
> To make the animation consume less CPU (and be smoother), don’t
>   animate the element deep in DOM.

This is referring to vanilla JS - is it outdated advice? Does jQuery have this issue or does it do something clever to avoid it?

Comment: I believe it's still true for today's browsers, along with more "tips" now in animating with CSS: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/

Comment: Also keep in mind that jQuery *is* vanilla JS (internally). It's just a library.

Comment: @Derek thanks.  I was wondering if jQuery did something to mitigate this, perhaps by taking things out of the DOM to animate them, or otherwise trying to reduce the need to change the layout (for CSS changes to background colour, say).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does makes sense. By changing an element the browser will have to verify if this change affects anything 'up the chain'. You can bypass this by making that object independent of the layout. You can make it positioned absolute or animate a transform propriety. In that case the animated element should not affect anything on the page.

Yes, jQuery has that issue. If you want performantanimations you should use CSS or Native element.animate if available: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/05/Web-Animations---element-animate-is-now-in-Chrome-36